# About sat4j, how to use sat4j to solve pseudo boolean problems?

Tags: java, boolean, sat-solvers, constraint-satisfaction, sat4j

I have pseudo boolean problems and I need to solve it with sat4j.

Can someone help me?

Here's my problem:

- I have a list of variables named: a,b,c,d,e,f
- And I have a list of values represented by: #1, #2, #3.....
- h(a,#1) means assign #1 to a

I have some example constraints:

```
h(a,#1)=1
h(a,#1)+h(b,#1)+h(c,#1)=1
h(a,#1)+h(a,#5)>=1
h(b,#2)+h(b,#3)+h(b,#4)>=1
```

So many constraints like examples above.
Finally, I want a result of assign which values to which value.

How can I solve it with sat4J? How should I represent the constraints?

Comment: I wouldn't use a CNF solver on this.  SMT is a much better fit.

Comment: what kind of SMT solver? can you recommend one to me? i need to integrate the code with my java project, so i want a tool that both solve pesudo boolean problem and offers java API.

Comment: Z3 is a popular SMT solver that I've used recreationally.  I haven't tried to use Java to talk to it, but others have, at least according to Google.  Z3's simple LISPy I/O syntax won't be hard to parse in any event.

Comment: yeah, i know the tool z3, but it doesn't offer java api.

Comment: Looks like other people have already done the API work.  I suspect it will be easier to use Z3 than coding adders and comparison circuits, which is what you'll need to do to use a CNF-based solver.

Comment: @KyleJones A pseudo-boolean solver like `org.sat4j.pb` doesn’t require manually built adders and comparators to express these constraints.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly as a pseudo-boolean satisfaction problem, you can directly encode it as an [OPB file](http://www.cril.univ-artois.fr/PB16/format.pdf):

```
* #variable= 7 #constraint= 4
1 x1 = 1;
1 x1 1 x2 1 x3 = 1;
1 x1 1 x4 >= 1;
1 x5 1 x6 1 x7 >= 1;
```

where I have arbitrarily encoded `h(a,#1)` as `x1`, `h(b,#1)` as `x2`, `h(c,#1)` as `x3`, `h(a,#5)` as `x4`, `h(b,#2)` as `x5`, `h(b,#3)` as `x6`, and `h(b,#4)` as `x7`.  (You may wish to add constraints like

```
-1 x1 -1 x4 >= -1;
-1 x2 -1 x5 -1 x6 -1 x7 >= -1;
```

stating that each variable has at most one value, or `=` for exactly one value.)

Then run

```
java -jar org.sat4j.pb.jar yourfile.opb
```

which outputs (ignoring many comment lines beginning with `c`):

```
s SATISFIA@KyleJones You don’t need to manually build adders and comparators to use a pseudo-boolean solver like `org.sat4j.pb`.BLE
v x1 -x2 -x3 -x4 x5 -x6 -x7
```

meaning `x1` and `x5` are true while `x2`, `x3`, `x4`, `x6`, and `x7` are false.

(I’m sure there’s a way to do the same thing using the [`org.sat4j.pb` Java API](http://www.sat4j.org/maven234/org.ow2.sat4j.pb/apidocs/org/sat4j/pb/package-summary.html), but perhaps this command-line recipe gives you a starting point to help you figure that out.)